# UIButton with an image and text

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, uibutton

I know there are several questions regarding the placement of images and text in buttons, but I still can't quite get it to work. I want the title to display below the image. If there is no image, the title displays where I would expect. However, if there is an image, the title does not display.

The code is pasted below.  Tomorrow I can try subclassing UIButton and tweaking the subviews, but this *should* work.  I think. Can you see why it wouldn't?

Thanks in advance!

```
private static float h = 200.0f;
private static float w = 200.0f;
private static float padding = 10.0f;
private static float textheight = 20f;

for (int i=0; i<numPlants; i++)
{
    var button = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
    button.Frame = new RectangleF (padding * (i + 1) + (i * w),
                                   padding, w, (h + textheight + 2));
    UIImage img = _group.Plants[i].GetImage();
    if (img != null)
    {
        button.SetImage(img, UIControlState.Normal);
        button.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0.0f, 0.0f, (textheight + 20), 0.0f);
    }

    button.TitleEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets((h+2), 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
    button.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);             
    button.SetTitle(_group.Plants[i].Pltnme, UIControlState.Normal);

    plantScrollView.AddSubview (button);

    Plant plt = _group.Plants[i];   
    button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
        _navController.PushViewController(new SecondViewController(plt), true);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using XIB or Storyboard and then adding a UIImageView and Label to create what you are desiring? I feel that this would be a lot simpler than coding it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I could do that, too. I'm still using the indie version, so I'm trying to keep the code as small as humanly possible.  The other problem with that method is that I still need the button functionality, so I'd need to put a transparent button on top of it.  In reading how other people have implemented this sort of functionality, this method looked like it would be the easiest.